# How do I get the x64 Native Tools Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a 64 bit Windows 10 and have installed the 2019 community edition Visual Studio. When I do a search for "x64" in Windows there is only an x86 developer command prompt and a PowerShell prompt.

What do I do to get the x64 developer command prompt for visual studio 2019?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my case it is named `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019` and I can find it using the following sequence:

1. Press `Windows` key.
2. Release `Windows` key.
3. Type `x64`.

The following screen appears:

[image: x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019]

You can also find shortcuts for VS 2019 Command Prompts (x86/x64, Native/Cross) here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2019\Visual Studio Tools\VC
```

[image: shortcuts for Command Prompts (x86/x64, Native/Cross)]

If nothing is found here, then check whether VS 2019 is correctly installed.

Comment: Oh, you mean, press Win key AND RELEASE, and then 'x64'.  I had used Win as a modifier, and it launched Firefox and Settings.

Comment: @OsamaBinLogin Yes, "and release". I've edited the answer.