# fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no search path for included files is specified. GraalVM Native Image did not compile my project

Tags: java, visual-studio, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

GraalVM did not compile my project, I tried this:

```
PS D:\Documents\Intellij Idea Projects\Project> ./gradlew.bat nativeRun

Configure project :
Project : => 'com.user.Project' Java module

Task :nativeCompile
[native-image-plugin] GraalVM Toolchain detection is disabled
[native-image-plugin] GraalVM location read from environment variable: JAVA_HOME
[native-image-plugin] Native Image executable path: C:\Users\user.jdks\graalvm-jdk-17.0.9\bin\native-image.cmd
=======================================================================================================================
GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'Project' (executable)...
========================================================================================================================For detailed information and explanations on the build output, visit:
https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/BuildOutput.md

[1/8] Initializing... (0,0s @ 0,09GB)
Error: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-5906854269780920035\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c). Compiler command ''D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe' /WX /W4 /wd4201 /wd4244 /wd4245 /wd4800 /wd4804 /wd4214 '/FeC:\Users\JustDeax\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-5906854269780920035\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.exe' 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-5906854269780920035\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c'' output included error: [AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c, C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-5906854269780920035\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c(1): fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no search path for included files is specified]
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
                    1,1s (11,4% of total time) in 19 GCs | Peak RSS: 0,43GB | CPU load: 2,91
========================================================================================================================
Finished generating 'Project' in 8,4s.

Task :nativeCompile FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':nativeCompile'.
Process 'command 'C:\Users\user.jdks\graalvm-jdk-17.0.9\bin\native-image.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 13s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

My Visual Studio with the required components is not in the default directory, maybe I need to add something to the environment variable

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: ok, I did the formatting, forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Run the gradle command from "Native Tools Command Prompt" that will bring all VS path in order.

You can see how to run that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62161113/175554)

Reference: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4104