Spring Boot 3.2.4 native build Issues
Following Introducing GraalVM Native Images with the end goal to convert my Spring Boot 3.2.4 spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws lambda function from a jar to a native 86_64 binary.
Most all the tutorials and blogs are using old org.springframework.experimental dependency.
Environment:

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2022 installed with C++ build pack
GRAALVM 22

$ java --version
java 22 2024-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 22+36.1 (build 22+36-jvmci-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 22+36.1 (build 22+36-jvmci-b02, mixed mode, sharing


pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bar.aws</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-hello</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>native-hello</name>
    <description>native-hello</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${artifactId}</imageName>
                    <docker>
                        <host>tcp://localhost:2375</host>
                    </docker>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

$ ./mvnw -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.4:build-image failed: Host name must not be empty


$ mvn -Pnative native:compile

[INFO] --- native:0.9.28:compile (default-cli) @ native-hello ---
[INFO] Found GraalVM installation from JAVA_HOME variable.
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.14]: Configuration directory not found. Trying latest version.
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.14]: Configuration directory is ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.4.1
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.4]: Configuration directory not found. Trying latest version.
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.4]: Configuration directory is com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.15.2
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.19]: Configuration directory not found. Trying latest version.
[INFO] [graalvm reachability metadata repository for org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.19]: Configuration directory is org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.0.20
[INFO] Executing: C:\sfw\java\graalvm-jdk\bin\native-image.cmd @target\tmp\native-image-4912974344800363771.args
Warning: The option '-H:ResourceConfigurationResources=META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/tomcat-resource.json' is experimental and must be enabled via '-H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions' in the future.
Warning: The option '-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources=META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/tomcat-reflection.json' is experimental and must be enabled via '-H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions' in the future.
Warning: The option '-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources=META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/tomcat-reflection.json' is experimental and must be enabled via '-H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions' in the future.
Warning: The option '-H:ReflectionConfigurationResources=META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/tomcat-reflection.json' is experimental and must be enabled via '-H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions' in the future.
Warning: The option '-H:ResourceConfigurationResources=META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/tomcat-resource.json' is experimental and must be enabled via '-H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions' in the future.
Warning: The option '-H:ResourceConfigurationResources=META-INF/native-image/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/tomcat-resource.json' is experimental and must be enabled via '-H:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions' in the future.
Warning: Please re-evaluate whether any experimental option is required, and either remove or unlock it. The build output lists all active experimental options, including where they come from and possible alternatives. If you think an experimental option should be considered as stable, please file an issue.
Error: Failed to automatically set up Windows build environment.
Please make sure that Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1.0 or later is installed on your system. You can download it at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. If this error persists, please try and run GraalVM Native Image in an x64 Native Tools Command Prompt or file a ticket.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.976 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-02T11:42:32-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.28:compile (default-cli) on project native-hello: Execution of C:\sfw\java\graalvm-jdk\bin\native-image.cmd @target\tmp\native-image-4912974344800363771.args returned non-zero result 


could you try to run your native compile command from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62161113/175554 ?
